# Get running total of consecutive values

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I have a table that stores the hours reported by users for activities completed, by reporting year and month. I have a function in an old Oracle database, that I need to replicate in SQL Server, that shows the current value for consecutive 0 hour reports. i.e. when someone hasn't reported hours for 3 months in a row, the number would be 3, if they have reported for a given month, the counter would then be reset back to 0, so as to only count the consecutive reports with 0 hours.

The table is always pre-filled with the expected amount of reporting periods for the user. i.e. if the user is expected to report hours for 6 months, we create the 6 rows in this table, with NULL in the *HOURS_REPORTED* field.

Here is a sample of the PLSQL.

```
FUNCTION FN_NIL_RPT_CNT ( PI_USER_ID IN NUMBER )
 RETURN NUMBER
 IS

 LV_NIL_CNT NUMBER := 0;

 CURSOR CR_DTLS IS
 SELECT YEAR
       ,MONTH
       ,HOURS_REPORTED
 FROM HOURS
 WHERE STATUS = 'CURRENT'
       AND USER_ID = PI_USER_ID
 ORDER BY TO_DATE(MONTH||YEAR, 'mmyyyy'); 

 BEGIN
   FOR LR_HR IN CR_DTLS
   LOOP
     EXIT WHEN TO_DATE(LR_HR.MONTH||LR_HR.YEAR,'mmyyyy') >= TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM');

     IF LR_HR.HOURS_REPORTED IS NOT NULL
     THEN
       IF LR_HR.HOURS_REPORTED = 0
       THEN
         LV_NIL_CNT := LV_NIL_CNT + 1;
       ELSE
         LV_NIL_CNT := 0;
       END IF;
     ELSE 
       NULL; -- ignore
     END IF;
   END LOOP;
 END;
 RETURN LV_NIL_CNT;
END FN_NIL_RPT_CNT;
```

So if the cursor contained the following, the expected result would be 2 because hours were reported in 2019/10, which would then reset the counter to 0, and the subsequent 2 months had 0 hours reported.

[image]

Comment: Do you want the number of consecutive "0" reported hours. As an example you have shown, what would be the expected output if the hours were 1,0,0,1,0,0

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph assuming those numbers were in order of year and month ascending, the count should show two as the last two months have had 0 reported, because the 1 reported 3 months back would have reset the count back to 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to make use of straight sql, and to lose the cursor logic. Anyday its going to be more efficient, faster and less expensive

Eg: the following query can get you the last_consecutive_count

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.t
(
    USER_ID INT
   ,YEAR INT
   ,MONTH INT
   ,HOURS_REPORTED INT
);

insert into dbo.t
VALUES
( 254, '2017', '12', 0 ), 
( 254, '2018', '01', 8 ), 
( 254, '2018', '02', 11 ), 
( 254, '2018', '03', 16 ), 
( 254, '2018', '04', 12 ), 
( 254, '2018', '05', 16 ), 
( 254, '2018', '06', 20 ), 
( 254, '2018', '07', 14 ), 
( 254, '2018', '08', 12 ), 
( 254, '2018', '09', 11 ), 
( 254, '2018', '10', 22 ), 
( 254, '2018', '11', 10 ), 
( 254, '2018', '12', 6 ), 
( 254, '2019', '01', 11 ), 
( 254, '2019', '02', 12 ), 
( 254, '2019', '03', 5 ), 
( 254, '2019', '04', 12 ), 
( 254, '2019', '05', 10 ), 
( 254, '2019', '06', 9 ), 
( 254, '2019', '07', 10 ), 
( 254, '2019', '08', 9 ), 
( 254, '2019', '09', 0 ), 
( 254, '2019', '10', 4 ), 
( 254, '2019', '11', 8 ), 
( 254, '2019', '12', 0 ), 
( 254, '2020', '01', 0 ), 
( 254, '2020', '02', 5 ),
( 254, '2020', '03', 7 )



WITH data
AS (SELECT *
          ,CAST(CONCAT(YEAR, '-', MONTH, '-01') AS DATE) AS dt
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY YEAR desc, MONTH desc) AS rnk
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by case when hours_reported=0 then 1 end ORDER BY YEAR desc, MONTH desc) AS rnk2
          ,DATEADD(MONTH, -ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH), CAST(CONCAT(YEAR, '-', MONTH, '-01') AS DATE)) AS grp
    FROM dbo.t
    WHERE USER_ID = 254 /* you can parameterize this in your sql server function*/
    )
   ,last_val
    as(SELECT *
          ,case when hours_reported<>0 then rnk else rnk-rnk2 end as val1
          ,rank() over(order by case when hours_reported<>0 then rnk else rnk-rnk2 end) as rnk_min
      FROM data
     )
select count(*) as last_consec_cnt
  from last_val
 where rnk_min=1


+----------------------+
| last_consecutive_cnt |
+----------------------+
|                    1 |
+----------------------+
```

You can put this in a function and pass the user_id to the table..

Here is a db fiddle link.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=9ac60e62a99e2465cc8e979ae9f29f7c

Comment: I definitely don't want to use a cursor, that's just old school Oracle code for you :)
I don't want the last consecutive count, I want the current consecutive count. I have made a change to your fiddle. If the last reported value is NOT 0, then it doesn't work as expected. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=db7e1900de9b89bc0bd51d7cfa17912b

Comment: :-) cool, I have edited the answer to cater to the cases where the results are limited to the current date

Comment: you want the last consecutive count, regardless of whether its 0?

Comment: Not really, I need to know the current running total of missed reports. So if they didn't report hours for 3 months, but reported hours this/current month, then the value should be 0 as they have reported their hours for the month. I've updated the fiddle with an actual case from my real dataset: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=5f92f26b6fb6608193c11387495c1246

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check the following link https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=572e38e4337a9813aec2455795e46f03

Comment: Please check this link, which is a simplified version https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=7a6e23c63a9bb7c06df6b07372b3dfa7

Comment: Thanks, that's a little closer to what I am after, however I have found a few cases where it doesn't work. One is where there are only 0 hours reported, for all reporting periods. For now, I have written a cursor inside a function similar to the Oracle one, but it performs much better.

Comment: i have updated the answer, to give you a sql solution only, catering to the cases for all 0 reported hours and all other cases

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=1f3f7098daa5980d732bb8a97a595828

Comment: Thanks, that will have to do for now :) It's still not always returning the exact same result, but I think I can tweak it from here.